# How to delete the correct record with multiple checkboxes using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a loop that generates rows of data. If I use chrome developer tool, I can see that each row has a unique value for `data-host-id`. However, when I click on any of the records, it always updates the very first record. It's not honoring the record I would like to update.

Note: I'm not looking to delete multiple records at the same time, I just want to delete the appropriate record via its associated button.

## Snippet of HTML code

```
<input data-size="mini" type="checkbox" class="switch-api" 
    data-on-text="Yes" data-off-text="No" id="api_id" data-host-id="{{ $k }}" checked>
```

## snippet of JS code

```
$(".switch-api").bootstrapSwitch();
$('.switch-api').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
if (state) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/dashboard/'+ $('#api_id').attr('data-host-id') + '/toggleapicheck',
        data: { api_id: $('#api_id').attr('data-host-id'), state:'true'},
```

## Controller

```
public function toggleapicheck(Request $request)
{
    $api_id = $request->input('api_id');
    $state = $request->input('state');
    $dashboard = new Dashboard();
    $dashboard->toggleApicheck($api_id, $state);
}
```

## Model

```
function toggleApicheck($api_id, $state)
{
    $sf = new \SensioLabs\Consul\ServiceFactory(array('base_url' => "http://127.0.0.1:8500"));
    $kv = $sf->get('kv');
    $kv->put('apichecks/'.$api_id.'/enable',$state);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**There are 2 issues:**

1. You have many `<input> tags`. But you force it to use the same `id="api_id"`. And other actions you write **depend** on this ID **=>** So you can **only** access to **first** **item** with that ID **=>** Why it causes problem **=>** Solution: move `api_id` to `data-api-id` attribute
2. You should use data() instead of attr() to get HTML data attribute

**Try my solution. I think it makes more sense**


***- HTML***

```
<input data-size="mini" type="checkbox" class="switch-api" 
    data-on-text="Yes" data-off-text="No" data-api-id="api_id" data-host-id="{{ $k }}" checked>
```

***- JS***

```
$(".switch-api").bootstrapSwitch();
$('.switch-api').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
if (state) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/dashboard/'+ $(this).data('host-id') + '/toggleapicheck',
        data: { api_id: $(this).data('api-id'), state:'true'},
```